# Ler arquivo de Word sem perder formatação

Tags: php, upload, sistema-de-arquivos, microsoft-word

Como ler um arquivo de Word sem perder a formatação do mesmo?

Situação: O cliente quer fazer a upload de um arquivo Word e guardamos tudo isso dentro do banco de dados como texto (para futuras buscas e semelhantes).

Obs: Usando apenas PHP.

Comment: Tem duas formas, pode salvar o arquivo no sistema de arquivos ou como blob no banco de dados.

Comment: Nunca olhei como o WordPress faz isso, mas ele tem uma função de `paste from Word` que pode ser interessante.

Comment: Não entendo a pergunta, especialmente dada a situação que você descreveu. Quer saber como extrair o texto do doc para salvar no banco?

Comment: Isso, porém sem perder a formatação.

Comment: Ah, então parece que você quer converter para HTML e salvar como HTML no banco. Existem bibliotecas para isso, mas é impossível garantir que nenhuma formatação seja perdida. Uma parte acaba perdendo.

Answer (score 1):

Para ler sem perder a formatação, salve o registro no banco de dados com um campo contendo o conteúdo extraído em formato de texto puro e o arquivo original em um local específico usando o ID do registro.

Use o campo para buscas por conteúdo e se o usuário quiser recuperar o arquivo via *download* você pode ler o arquivo original pelo ID e enviar para ele via PHP.